# angular ng-repeat filter with conditions?

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing an angular app, and want to display customer results in a table using ng-repeat. I can hook up ng-filter to an ng-model and search the results, but I'd like to know how I can add in checkboxes to modify my results.

For example, say I have this data:

```
[{
    "name": "Bob Smith",
    "percent": 100,
    "notes": "100 percent complete"
 },
 {
    "name": "Sally Brown",
    "percent": 75,
    "notes": "Not yet at 100 percent"
 }
    ....
 ]
```

My current app lets users search for anything in here, like a regular ng-repeat with a filter would:

```
<input ng-model="query.$">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Percent</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:query">
        <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.percent }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.notes }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input ng-model="query.completed" type="checkbox"> Show Completed Jobs
```

But I'd like a checkbox on the side that says "Show customers with 100%". I've tried writing a filter function:

```
.filter('show100percent', function() {
    return function(items, showcompleted) {
        var jobs = []
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            if (showcompleted == false) {
                if (item.percent < 100) {
                    jobs.push(item)
                }
            } else {
                jobs.push(item)
            }
        })
        return jobs
    }
})
```

But doing so stops my app from accepting input from the textbox

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | show100percent:query.completed">
```

And adding my filter on top of the regular filter just shows a blank set of results:

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | show100percent:query.completed | filter:query">
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I make my data searchable via the inputbox, but modify the results with a checkbox, select, second inputbox or any other kind of form element?

Comment: try changing `query.completed` to another object other than `query`. Since you pass `query` to `filter` there is no matching field

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different `$scope` variable to assign for check box and in custom filter, Right now showcompleted being sent as undefined. So filtering does not happen

```
  $scope.showcompleted = false;

  <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | show100percent:showcompleted | filter:query">
```

also in checkbox,

And i have modified your filter a bit

```
app.filter('show100percent', function() {
  return function(items, showcompleted) {
    var jobs = []
    items.forEach(function(item) {
      if (showcompleted == true) {
        if (item.percent == 100) {
          jobs.push(item)
        }

      } else {
        jobs.push(item)
      }
    })
    return jobs
  }
})
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/KoncPMyC1GEgRZ3kv145?p=preview)**

Comment: no additional filter is needed, just use angular native filter with extended query object, with 2 members: '$' to match any value within ng-repeated JSON and 'percent' - to match only percent value in JSON. See my answer and its plunker

Comment: @Andriy I know that, the solution with go with OPs question

Answer (score 0):

add *percent* attribute to your *query* object to match your model, so when check box is on, it should look like:

```
{
  $: FREE_TEXT,
  percent: 100
}
```

to achieve it with check box use `ng-true-value="100"` and empty `ng-false-value` directives:

```
<input ng-model="query.$">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Percent</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:query">
        <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.percent }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.notes }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input ng-model="query.percent" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="100" ng-false-value> Show Completed Jobs
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/uU6ibIDaS3OcYnZ3TqkR?p=preview